# How to vectorize rowwise join

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I've been given a dataframe `df` and a function `foo(int x)` that returns a Series.  I'd like to join `df` with the result of `foo()` for each row using a vectorized operation.

For example, given the following dataframe, I call `foo()` on the values of column `col_1`

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 'a' |
| 12 | 2 | 'b' |
| 13 | 3 | 'd' |
| 4 | 4 | 'c' |

If we assume

- `foo(1)  = Series('col4': 0, 'col5': 2)`
- `foo(12) = Series('col4': 1, 'col5': 3)`
- `foo(13) = Series('col4': 1, 'col5': 4)`
- `foo(4)  = Series('col4': 0, 'col5': 5)`

then the output should be

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 'a' | 0 | 2 |
| 12 | 2 | 'b' | 1 | 3 |
| 13 | 3 | 'd' | 1 | 4 |
| 4 | 4 | 'c' | 0 | 5 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Looks like `.from_records` will handle the map cleanly. You could try that with the `pd.concat` instead:

```
In [118]: pd.DataFrame.from_records(df['col_1'].map(foo))
Out[118]:
   col4  col5
0     0     2
1     1     3
2     1     4
3     0     5
```

Normally, I'd use `.map()` for something like this since it's generally faster than `.apply()`, but the output comes out a little funky, so unless you've got a giant dataframe, I'd just use the straightforward `.apply()` option with `pd.concat`:

```
In [18]: def foo(n):
    ...:     return {1: pd.Series({'col4': 0, 'col5': 2}), 12: pd.Series({'col4': 1, 'col5': 3}), 13: pd.Series({'col4': 1, 'col5': 4}), 4: pd.Series
    ...: ({'col4': 0, 'col5': 5})}[n]
    ...:

In [19]: df
Out[19]:
   col_1  col_2 col_3
0      1      1   'a'
1     12      2   'b'
2     13      3   'd'
3      4      4   'c'

In [20]: pd.concat([df, df['col_1'].apply(foo)], axis=1)
Out[20]:
   col_1  col_2 col_3  col4  col5
0      1      1   'a'     0     2
1     12      2   'b'     1     3
2     13      3   'd'     1     4
3      4      4   'c'     0     5
```

Another option you might try is to have the function return a dictionary rather than a Series

Comment: How would I use `.map()`? `.apply()` seems to take ages

Comment: I don't know what your actual calculation in `foo` is but the easiest way would be to split it into separate functions for the `col4` and `col5` calculations and then do `df['col4'] = df['col1'].map(foo_c4)` and then similar for `col5`. That might be a little slower if you're essentially calculating both values in the same computation though.

Comment: Yup, the calculation can't really be broken down and `foo` actually returns 1126 rows so not really feasible. I was trying to use `map` earlier and this was the problem I couldn't figure out :)

Comment: Looks like `pd.DataFrame.from_records` cleans up the weird `.map` output. I've edited the answer to reflect that, so you might give that a try instead of the `.apply`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your function can't take anything but a scalar, you're restricted to using `Series.apply`. In fact, [it's almost as though your function was made exactly for this use case](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) ...

Since if the func returns a Series object, the final output will be a DataFrame that is easy to join to your original one. From here you use `pd.concat` along the proper axis

```py
pd.concat([df, df.iloc[:,0].apply(foo)], axis=1)
```